# Starlink: Battle for Atlas - DLC options explained

Tags: nintendo-switch, starlink

Looking over the different [Starlink bundles](https://www.dekudeals.com/search?q=starlink), I had the impression that "Deluxe Edition" was more complete than "Digital Edition". And while I had read that Fox McCloud is included with every Nintendo Switch version of the game, he's absent from the cover art of "Deluxe Edition". Now I'm not so sure. And what about the other three Starfox characters - do they need to be purchased separately with the "Starfox Team Pilot Pack"?

And is it true that the content from "Battle for Atlas Collection 1" is already included in "Deluxe Edition"?

[image: Starlink titles and DLC]

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found by visiting each product description page on Nintendo's website, and comparing them:

### [Deluxe Edition](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/starlink-battle-for-atlas-deluxe-edition-switch/)

> Start your adventure with the full first collection of the Starlink
> Fleet to defeat Grax with the Starlink: Battle for Atlas™ game, 6
> Starships, 10 Pilots, and 15 Weapons included.

`*` = These are also available as DLC in [Collection 1](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/starlink-battle-for-atlas-collection-1-pack-70070000003448-switch/), for those who own the [Digital Edition](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/starlink-battle-for-atlas-digital-edition-switch/dlc/)

**Starships:**

- Arwing (Nintendo Switch version only)
- Zenith
- Neptune `*`
- Pulse `*`
- Lance `*`
- Nadir `*`

**Pilots:**

- Fox McCloud (Nintendo Switch version only)
- Mason Rana
- Levi McCray `*`
- Judge `*`
- Chase da Silva `*`
- Hunter Hakka `*`
- Shaid `*`
- Razor Lemay `*`
- Eli Arborwood `*`
- Kharl Zeon `*`

**Weapons:**

- Flamethrower
- Frost Barrage
- Shredder
- Iron Fist `*`
- Crusher `*`
- Shockwave `*`
- Hailstorm `*`
- Levitator `*`
- Volcano `*`
- Imploder `*`
- Nullifier Missiles `*`
- Freeze Ray Mk.2 `*`
- Shredder Mk.2 `*`
- Gauss Gun Mk.2 `*`
- Meteor Mk.2 `*`

### [Collection 2 Pack](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/starlink-battle-for-atlas-collection-2-pack-70070000005782-switch/)

**Starships:**

- Skullscream
- Vantage
- Vigilance

**Pilots:**

- Rankor
- Fern Wilder
- Galla Joust
- Startail
- Haywire

**Weapons:**

- Tidal Wave
- Ice Mine
- Jaunt
- Gauss Gun
- Fury Cannon
- Freeze Ray
- Meteor
- Levitator Mk.2
- Volcano Mk.2
- Imploder Mk.2
- Nullifier Mk.2

### [Star Fox Team Pilot Pack](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/starlink-battle-for-atlas-digital-star-fox-team-pilot-pack-70050000011988-switch/)

This DLC is, as far as I can tell, only available for the Switch version of the game.

It adds the characters:

- Falco
- Peppy
- Slippy